# Using HTML table tags inside script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, configuration

Using this example https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-To-Generate-A-Table-From-A-CSV-File-CSV-Parser.html

I set up a HTML table that takes a CSV file from multiple Raspberry PIs (via SSH) and displays this CSV output as a HTML table:

```
2018-03-22 12:43:21,NM_Test.h264,-2
```

My HTML page runs the following script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>

<script>
    $.get('ssh.php', function(data) {
        // start the table
        var html = '<table">';
        // split into lines
        var rows = data.split("\n");
        // parse lines
        rows.forEach( function getvalues(ourrow) {
            // start a table row
            html += "<tr>";
            // split line into columns
            var columns = ourrow.split(",");
            html += "<td>" + columns[0] + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + columns[1] + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + columns[2] + "</td>";
            // close row
            html += "</tr>";
        })
        // close table
        html += "</table>";
        // insert into div
        $('#container').append(html);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My SSH.php:

```
// set up SSH2 conenctions using config.php to connect to multiple PIs and execute:

echo $ssh->exec('tail -1 /var/log/playlog.csv');
```

Config.php:

```
return [
[
    "name" : "test1",
    "ip" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 97,
    "key" : 'ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAA...c3=',
]
[ ... ]
];
```

In my HTML table how can I add column names such as:

```
<tr>
    <th>PI Name</th>
    <th>Date/Time</th>
    <th>Playing</th>
    <th>Error</th>
</tr>
```

But for the 'PI Name' column how can I return the corresponding 'name' that I have defined for each PI inside my config.php file?

I'm having difficulty with using HTML tags inside jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add the PI name as the first element in each row of your CSV file, so in PHP code not in JavaScript code.

CSV file should look like that:

```
test1,2018-03-22 12:43:21,NM_Test.h264,-2
```

After you adjusted CSV format, make this JavaScript changes:

```
<script>
    $.get('ssh.php', function(data) {
        // start the table
        var html = '<table>';
        // add column headers
        html += '<tr><th>PI Name</th><th>Date/Time</th><th>Playing</th><th>Error</th></tr>';
        // split into lines
        var rows = data.split('\n');
        // parse lines
        rows.forEach( function getvalues(ourrow) {
            // start a table row
            html += "<tr>";
            // split line into columns
            var columns = ourrow.split(",");
            html += "<td>" + columns[0] + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + columns[1] + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + columns[2] + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + columns[3] + "</td>";
            // close row
            html += "</tr>";
        })
        // close table
        html += "</table>";
        // insert into div
        $('#container').append(html);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, changing the CSV file is not an option, if there a way around?

Comment: Of course, you could take PI names from some other place (like a JSON generated from config.php) and store them in an ordered list. Then take the names from there and put as the first column.

Comment: But would that not make my web page load slower? Is there a way I can directly pull the PI names from my config.php file?

Comment: You need them in a JavaScript loop, so at some point you will have to convert them to JavaScript object. If you don't want to load them as an external file, you could generate this object dynamically at page creation.

Comment: It's difficult without knowing the structure of your code.

Comment: The code that I have for my HTML page is only missing general html tags such as `<!DOCTYPE html>`, apart from that I only have the code for  `$.get` function.